# Matrix functions via Cauchy integral

Tags: calculus, matrices, reference-request

I shall be much obliged if one provides me with references on calculation of "standard" matrix functions by use of Cauchy integral, such as

- matrix exponent
- matrix logarithm
- matrix square root
- matrix absolute value

Thank you.